# How to manage DTD URLs and avoid fetching DTD URL references to be fetched at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jetty, dtd

I have software running at different sites for over a decade now. That software uses, among other libraries, Hibernate and Jetty. Both of those have XML configuration files that have a DOCTYPE declaration with an http:// URL. Yes, HTTP, because 10 years ago HTTPS wasn't the default for such public resources.

Now a few months ago the system wouldn't build any more because of some of these URLs having vanished. Like old Jetty at mortbay.org, or hibernate at sourceforge and things like that. Interestingly the JETTY URL at mortbay.org was defunct for years, but it was never a problem.

But with Hibernate it has become a real problem. It does seem to actually go out and try to make those connections to these hibernate.org servers, and they changed twice, and the chain of redirects failed somewhere, then their certificate got updated. It has become a holy mess!

These DTDs should never be grabbed from the internet. I frankly don't even know how our system could ever have worked behind some egress firewall that never planned for these calls to succeed.

I know in the old days of SGML and DTDs there was something like a "catalog" which would come and serve these DTDs and other imported entities. But that was before the URL was invented.

I then went in and changed all those URLs to classpath URLs (I have my own protocol handler for that) and I put these DTD files into the classpath. After a lot of searching and editing of all of these files, I managed to get it to work. Since the .dtd files are actually somewhere in the classpath.

For example, for the hibernate one I give:

```
classpath:/org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

and that works. Initially that was:

```
http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

and that reference broke somehow. So it had to be replaced with

```
https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

which then broke because of some PKIX SSL problems. This has finally (after over 10 years) directed my attention to this problem.

Perhaps there once was something that caught the http://.../hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd and replaced it with getting /org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd from the classpath. But that might have broken down as soon as the URL scheme was changed from http: to https:, maybe, just guessing.

So, I want to know how this was ever supposed to work in general with these DTDs being sourced with HTTPS? URLs potentially making slow calls to the internet every time such a file is opened?

And of course "it depends" on which XML parser or processor you use. But that's the thing, we don't often even control that. These configuration XML files are read with whatever thing they want, so I am not asking for what a special solution of some special package could be. I am asking for how this is supposed to work in general?

With Schema namespaces it's not a problem, these URIs aren't actually referenced. To get the XSD files, you can specify an xsi:schemaLocation but you don't have to and anyway it's not equal to the namespace URI. With DTDs, some you don't even need, because you don't need instance validation in many cases, but some DTDs you do need because certain XML functions, such as ID and IDREF do not even work unless a basic DTD attributes definitions have been made, and then there are entity replacements, etc. So DTDs are sometimes needed to process an XML file at all. And that's where the problem with these URLs comes in.

If you want a specific example for the problem see here: [Hibernate 3.5 throws "org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270479/hibernate-3-5-throws-org-dom4j-documentexception-error-on-line-1-of-document-h)

Comment: Java since version 9 has https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/core/xml-catalog-api1.html and additionally Norman Walsh has https://xmlresolver.org/ or for Java https://github.com/xmlresolver/xmlresolver. Can't tell how those fit into hibernate.

Comment: If you use Jetty properly, the DTDs and XSDs that Jetty and your webapps use are never fetched over the internet. (Jetty manages all of these from content within the official Jetty jars)